# fill an object inside another object using useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

my main idea is to try to do everything in a single object but I had no idea how to do it, that's why I chose to separate it into 2 objects:

Object 1

```
const [truck, setTruck] = useState ({
        DriId: "",
        TruExdate: "",
        TruAddress: ""})
```

object 2:

```
const [stateTruck, StateTruck] = setState ({
   sruId: ""
})
```

Then I want to consolidate everything into a single object in this way.

```
const [truck, setTruck] = useState ({
        DriId: "",
        TruExdate: "",
        TruAddress: "",
        StateTruck: [
            {
            sruId: ""
            },
            {
            sruId: ""
            },...
        ],
        TraUnit: "",
        TraMake: "",
        TraYear: "",
        TtyId: "",
        TraIntmaterial: "",
        TraEquipament: "",
        TraOption: ""
    });
```

How could I do it?

Comment: What are you not able to do using a single object?

Comment: I did not understand your question well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely could do it, and in many case you should do it.

*Things that change together should stay together.*

I wrote a simple code where I use and change a compound state inside a SFC.

Always be careful about passing the old Truck state when you're setting a new Truck state.
Even if changing a single properties.

I hope this answer will help you!

```js
const {useState} = React;

const Truck = props => {
  
  const [truck, setTruck] = useState ({
    DriId: "02481445",
    TruExdate: "...",
    TruAddress: "-",
    StateTruck: [
      {
        sruId: "93153"
      },
      {
        sruId: "21651"
      },
      // ...
    ],
    // ...
  });
  const changeAddress = () => {
    setTruck(
      {
        ...truck,
        TruAddress: 'Sunset Boulevard, 15',
      }
    );
  };

  const changeState = () => {
    const newState = truck.StateTruck;
    newState.push({
      sruId: "46531"
    });
    setTruck(
      {
        ...truck,
        StateTruck: newState,
      }
    );
  };
  
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={changeState}>Add SRU Id</button>
      <button onClick={changeAddress}>Change Address</button>

      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Driver Id</td>
          <td>{truck.DriId}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Truck Address</td>
          <td>{truck.TruAddress}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>SRU Ids</td>
          <td>
            <ul>
              {truck.StateTruck.map((i) => (<li key={i.sruId}>{i.sruId}</li>))}
            </ul>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <Truck />,
  document.body
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```